# Открытие меню выбора файлов при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android

Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку открывалось меню выбора файла из внутренней памяти или флешки. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать платформу доступа к хранилищу (Storage Access Framework)
Платформа SAF облегчает пользователям поиск и открытие документов, изображений и других файлов в хранилищах всех поставщиков, с которыми они работают.
Вот пример функции по открытию окна выбора файла из хранилища, её можно вызвать при нажатии на кнопку:

```
public void performFileSearch() {

 // Создаём новый интент для доступа к хранилищу
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

 // Фильтруем результаты на те, которые можно "открыть"
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

 // Показываем только картинки (ещё один фильтр)
 intent.setType("image/*");
 // запускаем интент
 startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Обработка результатов:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
    Intent resultData) {

if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)  {
     // возвращаем URI нужного документа
     Uri uri = null;
     if (resultData != null) {
         uri = resultData.getData();
         Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
         showImage(uri); //функция для показа документа (реализуйте сами)
     }
 }
}
```

[image: Вот как-то так это должно выглядеть]
[Источник](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

Answer (score 1):

Очень абстрактный вопрос. Но самый простой способ получить доступ к файлу на Android - это использовать `Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выберите файлы с помощью..."), REQUEST_TAKE_DOCUMENTS);
```

Запуская этот код из Activity вы можете получить ответ в переопределённом методе:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
 {
  switch(requestCode)
  {
   case REQUEST_TAKE_DOCUMENTS:
...
   return;
  }
 }
}
```

В данном случае в объекте `data` будут данные об одном файле:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

Или о группе выбранных файлов:

```
ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
```